# Can we create singleton object by declaring all its methods and variables static?

Tags: java

I know how to create a singleton object by declaring its constructor private. But my doubt is: can we create a singleton object by declaring all its methods and variables static. If so, what challenges we will face?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you declare all methods and variables of a class `static`, you can still create arbitrary many instances of that class. These objects will have only the inherited methods and variables. But all newly declared methods and variable are global. That is very similar to a singleton object, but not the same.

E.g. let's say you have a singleton class implementing the Collection interface, than you can have only one instance. But you are free to give it to any method requiring a collection instance. That is impossible when you make everything in a class static.

Making members of classes static means you use the class not as class but as a namespace.

Answer (score 0):

by declaring all variables and methods static, you are practiacally making it **not an object**. 
It will be **similar to a c program with global variables** more then a singleton pattern - very not OOP style!

You will also make it impossible for this class to implement any interface [remember there is no overriding with static methods...] again, not very OOP style.

Answer (score 0):

When you do that, you can create as many instances of the class as you like, though the underlying things will remain unchanged.

Even if you don't create any instance, the attributes will remain: because static elements are properties of the **class**, not the **object**.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you're in the case where singleton is not needed because almost all your methods are static, that say that you don't have to retains any state in any object... like a singleton is designed for.

A singleton is a stateful object offering static methods, like would be a ConnectionPool's singleton for instance, that retains information about the underlying backend service.

So, I'd do is to decide whether you need some shared state to be kept in order to execute your methods. It will drive your implementation.